# Python - move specific rows of columns in csv file

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I'm new to Python. I have no idea the way to move specific rows of columns in csv file.

As shown in the picture below, I would like to move columns B and C to the right (column D) where column D does not have value.

Thanks a lot.

desired outcome

[image]

Code:

```py
import csv
import pandas as pd

filename=(".csv")
data=pd.read_csv(filename)
```

Comment: you should provide some condition.like which content need to move.in your question you want move the whole column B and C to C and D.but you intend result only removed two rows

Comment: The way you provide a picture of your desired outcome is excellent! It makes it very easy for people to read the question and answer it! I see you confuse csv (file format) with pandas.DataFrame (data format), so I will quickly edit your question to make it work and researchable by others with the same issue. Otherwise, Great job!

Comment: Please provide an example of the CSV file you are working with. That will tell us how the "missing" column elements are described (e.g. are they indicated with successive commas like ",," or they just aren't there at all. Once you know that, then you'll be able to specify column operations in pandas, something like df['d'] = df['d' == None]['c']

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you only want remove rows without nil.
so I write a simple example for this

```py
#split Nil and None Nil
df1 = data[data['D']=='Nil']
df2 = data[data['D']!='Nil']

#move None Nil rows
df2['D'] = df2['C']
df2['C'] = df2['B']
df2['B'] = ["" for _ in range(len(df2['B']))]

#concat two dataframe
df_new = pd.concat([df1,df2])
df_new = df_new.sort_values(by='num')
```